# Rubik's Cube in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, breadth-first-search

I have this Java implementation of a Rubik's cube's state. My primary concern is DRYness of my code:

**`RubiksCubeNode.java`**

```
package net.coderodde.libid;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 *
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (May 4, 2019)
 */
public final class RubiksCubeNode {

    public enum Axis {
        X,
        Y,
        Z
    }

    public enum Direction {
        CLOCKWISE,
        COUNTER_CLOCKWISE
    }

    public enum Layer {
        LAYER_1(0),
        LAYER_2(1),
        LAYER_3(2);

        private final int layerNumber;

        private Layer(int layerNumber) {
            this.layerNumber = layerNumber;
        }

        public int toInteger() {
            return layerNumber;
        }
    }

    private final int[][][] data;

    private Set<RubiksCubeNode> neighbors;

    public RubiksCubeNode() {
        data = new int[3][3][3];

        for (int x = 0, value = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
                for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++) {
                    data[x][y][z] = value++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public RubiksCubeNode(RubiksCubeNode other) {
        this.data = new int[3][3][3];

        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
                for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++) {
                    data[x][y][z] = other.data[x][y][z];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public RubiksCubeNode rotate(Axis axis,
                                 Layer layer,
                                 Direction direction) {
        RubiksCubeNode nextNode = new RubiksCubeNode(this);

        switch (axis) {
            case X:
                rotateAroundXAxis(nextNode, direction, layer.toInteger());
                break;

            case Y:
                rotateAroundYAxis(nextNode, direction, layer.toInteger());
                break;

            case Z:
                rotateAroundZAxis(nextNode, direction, layer.toInteger());
                break;

            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown axis enum.");
        }

        return nextNode;
    }

    public Set<RubiksCubeNode> computeNeighbors() {
        if (neighbors != null) {
            return neighbors;
        }

        neighbors = new HashSet<>(18);

        for (Layer layer : Layer.values()) {
            for (Axis axis : Axis.values()) {
                for (Direction direction : Direction.values()) {
                    neighbors.add(rotate(axis, layer, direction));
                }
            }
        }

        return neighbors;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!o.getClass().equals(this.getClass())) {
            return false;
        }

        RubiksCubeNode other = (RubiksCubeNode) o;

        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
                for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++) {
                    if (data[x][y][z] != other.data[x][y][z]) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int i = 1;
        int hash = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
                for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++) {
                    hash += data[x][y][z] * i++;
                }
            }
        }

        return hash;
    }

    private static void rotateAroundXAxis(RubiksCubeNode node,
                                          Direction direction,
                                          int xLayer) {
        switch (direction) {
            case CLOCKWISE:
                rotateAroundXAxisClockwise(node, xLayer);
                break;

            case COUNTER_CLOCKWISE:
                rotateAroundXAxisCounterClockwise(node, xLayer);
                break;
        }
    }

    private static void rotateAroundYAxis(RubiksCubeNode node,
                                          Direction direction,
                                          int yLayer) {
        switch (direction) {
            case CLOCKWISE:
                rotateAroundYAxisClockwise(node, yLayer);
                break;

            case COUNTER_CLOCKWISE:
                rotateAroundYAxisCounterClockwise(node, yLayer);
                break;
        }
    }

    private static void rotateAroundZAxis(RubiksCubeNode node,
                                          Direction direction,
                                          int zLayer) {
        switch (direction) {
            case CLOCKWISE:
                rotateAroundZAxisClockwise(node, zLayer);
                break;

            case COUNTER_CLOCKWISE:
                rotateAroundZAxisCounterClockwise(node, zLayer);
                break;
        }
    }


    private static void rotateAroundXAxisClockwise(RubiksCubeNode node,
                                                   int xLayer) {
        int[][][] data = node.data;
        int saveValue1 = data[xLayer][0][0];
        int saveValue2 = data[xLayer][1][0];

        data[xLayer][1][0] = data[xLayer][0][1];
        data[xLayer][0][0] = data[xLayer][0][2];
        data[xLayer][0][1] = data[xLayer][1][2];
        data[xLayer][0][2] = data[xLayer][2][2];

        data[xLayer][1][2] = data[xLayer][2][1];
        data[xLayer][2][2] = data[xLayer][2][0];
        data[xLayer][2][1] = saveValue2;
        data[xLayer][2][0] = saveValue1;
    }

    private static void rotateAroundXAxisCounterClockwise(RubiksCubeNode node,
                                                          int xLayer) {
        int[][][] data = node.data;
        int saveValue1 = data[xLayer][0][0];
        int saveValue2 = data[xLayer][1][0];

        data[xLayer][0][0] = data[xLayer][2][0];
        data[xLayer][1][0] = data[xLayer][2][1];
        data[xLayer][2][0] = data[xLayer][2][2];
        data[xLayer][2][1] = data[xLayer][1][2];

        data[xLayer][2][2] = data[xLayer][0][2];
        data[xLayer][1][2] = data[xLayer][2][1];
        data[xLayer][0][2] = saveValue1;
        data[xLayer][0][1] = saveValue2;
    }

    private static void rotateAroundYAxisClockwise(RubiksCubeNode node, 
                                                   int yLayer) {
        int[][][] data = node.data;
        int saveValue1 = data[0][yLayer][0];
        int saveValue2 = data[0][yLayer][1];

        data[0][yLayer][1] = data[1][yLayer][0];
        data[0][yLayer][0] = data[2][yLayer][0];
        data[1][yLayer][0] = data[2][yLayer][1];
        data[2][yLayer][0] = data[2][yLayer][2];

        data[2][yLayer][1] = data[1][yLayer][2];
        data[2][yLayer][2] = data[0][yLayer][2];
        data[1][yLayer][2] = saveValue2;
        data[0][yLayer][2] = saveValue1;
    }

    private static void rotateAroundYAxisCounterClockwise(RubiksCubeNode node,
                                                          int yLayer) {
        int[][][] data = node.data;
        int saveValue1 = data[0][yLayer][0];
        int saveValue2 = data[0][yLayer][1];

        data[0][yLayer][0] = data[0][yLayer][2];
        data[0][yLayer][1] = data[1][yLayer][2];
        data[0][yLayer][2] = data[2][yLayer][2];
        data[1][yLayer][2] = data[2][yLayer][1];

        data[2][yLayer][2] = data[2][yLayer][0];
        data[2][yLayer][1] = data[1][yLayer][0];
        data[2][yLayer][0] = saveValue1;
        data[1][yLayer][0] = saveValue2;
    }

    private static void rotateAroundZAxisClockwise(RubiksCubeNode node,
                                                   int zLayer) {
        int[][][] data = node.data;
        int saveValue1 = data[0][0][zLayer];
        int saveValue2 = data[0][1][zLayer];

        data[0][1][zLayer] = data[1][0][zLayer];
        data[0][0][zLayer] = data[2][0][zLayer];
        data[1][0][zLayer] = data[2][1][zLayer];
        data[2][0][zLayer] = data[2][2][zLayer];

        data[2][1][zLayer] = data[1][2][zLayer];
        data[2][2][zLayer] = data[0][2][zLayer];
        data[1][2][zLayer] = saveValue2;
        data[0][2][zLayer] = saveValue1;
    }

    private static void rotateAroundZAxisCounterClockwise(RubiksCubeNode node,
                                                          int zLayer) {
        int[][][] data = node.data;
        int saveValue1 = data[0][0][zLayer];
        int saveValue2 = data[0][1][zLayer];

        data[0][0][zLayer] = data[0][2][zLayer];
        data[0][1][zLayer] = data[1][2][zLayer];
        data[0][2][zLayer] = data[2][2][zLayer];
        data[1][2][zLayer] = data[2][1][zLayer];

        data[2][2][zLayer] = data[2][0][zLayer];
        data[2][1][zLayer] = data[1][0][zLayer];
        data[2][0][zLayer] = saveValue1;
        data[1][0][zLayer] = saveValue2;
    }
}
```

**`RubiksCubeNodeTest`**

```
package net.coderodde.libid;

import junit.framework.TestCase;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * Tests the {@link RubiksCubeNode}. 
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (May 6, 2019)
 */
public class RubiksCubeNodeTest extends TestCase {

    @Test
    public void testRotation1() {
        RubiksCubeNode node = new RubiksCubeNode();
        node = node.rotate(RubiksCubeNode.Axis.X, 
                           RubiksCubeNode.Layer.LAYER_1,
                           RubiksCubeNode.Direction.CLOCKWISE);
        node = node.rotate(RubiksCubeNode.Axis.Z, 
                           RubiksCubeNode.Layer.LAYER_2, 
                           RubiksCubeNode.Direction.COUNTER_CLOCKWISE);
        RubiksCubeNode another = new RubiksCubeNode(node);
        assertEquals(node, another);
        assertEquals(another, node);
        assertEquals(node.hashCode(), another.hashCode());
        RubiksCubeNode third = new RubiksCubeNode(node);
        third = third.rotate(RubiksCubeNode.Axis.Y, 
                             RubiksCubeNode.Layer.LAYER_3,
                             RubiksCubeNode.Direction.CLOCKWISE);
        assertNotEquals(third, node);
        assertNotEquals(third, another);
        assertNotEquals(node.hashCode(), third.hashCode());
    }
}
```

(The idea for the class `RubiksCubeNode` is that the configurations comprise an undirected, unweighted graph. We put an edge between any two configurations if they are one rotation away from each other.)

For demonstration, consider forking [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/coderodde/LibID/tree/78a55aa36ba56ad57e5754f2eadb8f1d69761b83).

Typical output looks like this:

```
Bidirectional BFS path (57684 ms):
          net.coderodde.libid.RubiksCubeNode@1266
          net.coderodde.libid.RubiksCubeNode@1112
          net.coderodde.libid.RubiksCubeNode@12da
          net.coderodde.libid.RubiksCubeNode@12cc
          net.coderodde.libid.RubiksCubeNode@1488
          net.coderodde.libid.RubiksCubeNode@17ac
          net.coderodde.libid.RubiksCubeNode@1998
BIDDFS path (644 ms):
          net.coderodde.libid.RubiksCubeNode@1266
          net.coderodde.libid.RubiksCubeNode@1112
          net.coderodde.libid.RubiksCubeNode@12da
          net.coderodde.libid.RubiksCubeNode@12cc
          net.coderodde.libid.RubiksCubeNode@1488
          net.coderodde.libid.RubiksCubeNode@17ac
          net.coderodde.libid.RubiksCubeNode@1998
Algorithms returns correct paths: true
```

Comment: i hope i don't step into the same pitfall as last time - but why do you use `int[][][]` instead of proper `Data[][][]`? is it that **'competive style'** thing again? even then, you could name it better. maybe `int[][][] colorSet` instead of `int[][][] data`? - i know it doesn't concern DRY, so it's just a comment ^_^ - happy coding!!

Answer (score 1):

I have two comments:

1. regarding DRYness: this is how I would do it: I see that rotation involves assigning values to 8 cells in the 3d array. I would have `rotate()` calculate the source and target indices of the rotation based on args. then the actual assignment can be performed in one place. now, when you put all index-calculations in one place, you start noticing recurring patterns in all the various rotations so you can further reduce code duplication
2. there are two problems with the overall design: first, I don't like the static rotation methods. I mean, it seems right to me that a cube class should be able to rotate itself.   this relates to the 2nd point - IIUC, the `RubiksCubeNode` is intended to be node in graph. but it is also a `RubiksCube` that does all the cube's operations. this violates the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). a `GraphNode` is the buliding block of the graph and I would expect it to perform graph related operations, like traversal etc. the data of the `GraphNode` is an instance of `RubiKCube` that holds a snapshot of the cube and can perform cube related operations